# How to select a GROUPED BY average for a non-specific key in the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for a way to select the average for a particular user in the select statement and then calculate the variance in the current row from the previously calculated average.

The User and Attmept_Number is a composite key. In addition this should be done in either the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clause. I know of a solution using `FROM (SELECT...)`, but in this instance I am looking for a different solution.

```
SELECT 
    User, 
    Attmept_Number, 
    (User_Score - AVG(User_Score)) As Variance
FROM Scores
```

With the above statement, I am getting the column average, not the average for the user. When I add a `GROUP BY` clause it causes issues due to the Composite key.

Result:

```
User   Score   Variance
1      5       -6
1      10      -1
1      15      4
3      14      3
```

Goal:

```
User   Score   Variance
1      5       -5
1      10      0
1      15      5
3      14      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL 8.0, it's as simple as using window function `AVG(...) OVER(...)`:

```
SELECT
   user,
   score,
   score - AVG(score) OVER(PARTITION BY user) AS variance
FROM scores
```

In earlier versions, you can use an aggregate subquery to compute the average per user and then `JOIN` it with the table:

```
SELECT
   s.user,
   s.score,
   s.score - t.avg_score AS variance
FROM scores s
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user, AVG(score) avg_score FROM scores GROUP BY user
) t ON s.user = t.user
```